# C# Sort object array by specific parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am relatively new to programming. I have an array of objects which isn't necessarily full (may include null rows). And I want to sort it by one of the class parameters "int moveScore".
This is my array (currently holds only 32 entries)

```
Score[] firstPlyScore = new Score[1000];
```

I tried 2 things for sorting

**1**
In the "Score" class, i inherited "IComparable" and used the "CompareTo" method as follows

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Score x = (Score)obj;

            if (this.moveScore < x.moveScore)
                return -1;

            if (this.moveScore > x.moveScore)
                return 1;

            return 0;
        }
```

I called it using;

```
Array.Sort(firstPlyScore);
```

The problem is that it does sort correctly but at the end of the array. Meaning rows 0-966 are "null" and 967-999 are sorted correctly (967 with highest "int", 999 with lowest).
Is there any way to fix this.

**2**
I also tried this

```
Array.Sort(firstPlyScore, delegate
    (Score x, Score y) { return x.moveScore.CompareTo(y.moveScore); });
```

Here the problem was that it crashed when it reached a "null" row.

Help most appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to omit the null rows?

Comment: Have you considered using a list instead of an array? That way you can easily avoid those null entries.

Comment: to mfanto - I don't want to omit the null rows.

Comment: to Jon Skeet - I don't actually now how to use lists yet (still a student) :-)

Comment: @user3092553 `List<Score> scoreList = new List<Score>();`, that will create an 'open-ended' collection of `Score` objects, in which you can `Add()` to. See [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default comparison behavior is for `null` values to be ordered before non-`null` values.  If you want to override this behavior, a custom `Comparison<Score>` like in your second example would be the way to go.

```
delegate (Score x, Score y) {
    if (x == null)
        return y == null ? 0 : 1;
    if (y == null)
        return -1;
    return x.moveScore.CompareTo(y.moveScore);
}
```

This will keep the `null` items at the end of the array.

To sort in descending order, just swap the `x` and `y` references in the last line.

Comment: +1 because, as much as a think arrays here are poo, this ought to work work (and it won't "lose" all the `null` entries).

Comment: Thanks! This actually works only it sorts them in a ascending order. How do i get it to sort descending?

Comment: @user3092553, `return y.moveScore.CompareTo(x.moveScore);` should do it

Answer (score 3):

```
firstPlyScore = firstPlyScore
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.moveScore)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks! it works but... i need the array to be 1000 for future iterations. Is it possible to keep it at 1000?

Comment: @user3092553 just add `.Concat(firstPlyScore.Where(x => x == null))` after *OrderByDescending*.  Final linq would be:  `firstPlyScore = firstPlyScore
                        .Where(x => x != null)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.moveScore)
                        .Concat(firstPlyScore.Where(x => x == null))
                        .ToArray();`

Comment: Even though this does work, the code is quite verbose and would be hard to follow. The custom comparison option, above, is a better approach.

Comment: @Xenolightning `hard to follow`? maybe for you. not for all.

Comment: @L.B, Remove Nulls, Order Collection, Put Nulls Back, To Array. Seems like a lot of work to replace an `Array.Sort`

Comment: @Xenolightning maybe, But it shows another way of doing it with Linq. So unless it is wrong , it can be thought as an answer.

Comment: @Xenolightning BTW: Above code's complexity is still `O(n*lon(n))` (including the code in my comment)

Answer (score 2):

You  can use Linq to Entities to sort and then convert back to an array it will re-size your array  to the correct length needed without  null  issue

```
 var list = firstPlyScore.OrderByDescending(x => x.MoveScore).ToList();
       //here  how you can get always  1000 array  length  as you asked  
            for (int i = list.Count-1; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                list.Add(null);  
            }
            firstPlyScore = list.ToArray();  

        }
```

Comment: since there are some entries which are null x.MoveScore will fail

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get a "NullReferenceException".

Comment: Adding `where` and changing `Order` to `OrderByDescending` makes it *my answer* :)

Comment: thanks! it works but... 1) i need the array sorted in an descending order. 2) I do need the array to be 1000 for future iterations

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your compare method

```
if(obj == null) return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it does sort correctly but at the end of the
>   array. Meaning rows 0-966 are "null" and 967-999 are sorted correctly
>   (967 with highest "int", 999 with lowest). Is there any way to fix
>   this.

If you need something, whose size can change, you are looking for a `List<int>`, instead of using arrays.
Arrays should be used for Lists that **do not change** (e.g. a chess board).

The List also provides you a method called [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As mentioned by others, you can also use LINQ to achieve what you seek for.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to keep 1000 items in the list even if most of them are null ?
I would suggest to check the logic behind it to see if you can prevent that because that's taking a lot of space for nothing.

Otherwise, 2 possibilities:

1. Check for Obj == null in your compare function. But it might still fail if the comparing item is null
2. Create a custom class for your score and make Icomparable (Check [this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/) for several example about how to sort arrays